# Level-order repminPrint

Tags: haskell, tree, monads, breadth-first-search, tying-the-knot

`repmin` problem is pretty well-known. We are given a data type for trees:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | Fork (Tree a) a (Tree a) deriving Show
```

We need to write a function down (`repmin`) which would take a tree of numbers and replace all numbers in it by their minimum **in a single pass**. It is also possible to print the tree out along the way (let us say function `repminPrint` does this). Both `repmin` and pre-, post- and in-order `repminPrint` could be written down easily using value recursion. Here is an example for in-order `repminPrint`:

```
import Control.Arrow

replaceWithM :: (Tree Int, Int) -> IO (Tree Int, Int)
replaceWithM (Leaf a, m)      = print a >> return (Leaf m, a)
replaceWithM (Fork l mb r, m) = do 
                                  (l', ml) <- replaceWithM (l, m)
                                  print mb
                                  (r', mr) <- replaceWithM (r, m)
                                  return (Fork l' m r', ml `min` mr `min` mb)

repminPrint = loop (Kleisli replaceWithM)
```

But what if we want to write level-order `repminPrint` down?

My guess is that we cannot use the queue as we need the `ml` and `mr` to update the binding for `m`. I cannot see how this could be down with a queue. I wrote down an instance for level-order `Foldable Tree` to show what I mean:

```
instance Foldable Tree where
 foldr f ini t = helper f ini [t] where
  helper f ini []                 = ini
  helper f ini ((Leaf v) : q      = v `f` helper f ini q
  helper f ini ((Fork l v r) : q) = v `f` (helper f ini (q ++ [l, r]))
```

As you can see, we do not run anything on `l` and `r` during the current recursive call.

So, how could this be done? I would appreciate hints instead of full solutions.

Comment: I think the traversal order shouldn’t matter…I may be wrong, but I would reach for laziness: build a tree of the same shape as the input, where each value is replaced with a reference to the *same* “minimum” thunk, whose value is computed from the whole tree. You can do it with `ArrowLoop`, but I’d use `MonadFix` with `do`…`rec`… notation. Of course, while there’s only one *explicit* traversal in the source, at runtime there are two, in a way, interleaved: one for the tree’s *structure* (allocating a new tree whose nodes all point to the same thunk), one for its *values* (forcing the thunk).

Comment: I'm not sure if this is really doable: Consider how you can traverse the tree in BFS order and during this traversal also "reconstruct" it at the same time. This is a simpler problem than what you're aiming for, but is absolutely essential that you can do that first. How would you approach this simpler problem?

Comment: [might be related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60516485/building-a-binary-tree-not-bst-in-haskell-breadth-first). (also, @alias)

Comment: @WillNess That's quite tour-de-force. Does it only build "full" trees though? i.e., fully balanced? I suspect the OP's case is for a general tree.

Comment: @alias I think so, yes. left-biased in the fringe, too. otherwise it would have to return a list of trees, modeling the nondeterminism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to accomplish what you're looking to do here is with a traversal (in the sense of the `Traversable` class). First, I'm going to generalise a little bit to rose trees:

```hs
data Tree a
  = a :& [Tree a]
  deriving (Show, Eq, Ord, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)
```

All of the functions I show should be pretty straightforward to change into the tree definition you have given, but this type is a little more general and shows some of the patterns a little better I think.

Our first task, then, is to write the `repmin` function on this tree.
We also want to write it using the derived `Traversable` instance.
Luckily, the pattern done by `repmin` can be expressed using a combination of the reader and writer applicatives:

```hs
unloop :: WriterT a ((->) a) b -> b
unloop m = 
  let (x,w) = runWriterT m w
  in x
      
repmin :: Ord a => Tree a -> Tree a
repmin = unloop . traverse (WriterT .  f)
  where
    f x ~(Just (Min y)) = (y, Just (Min x))
```

While we're using the monad transformer version of `WriterT` here of course we don't need to, since Applicatives always compose.

The next step is to turn this into the `repminPrint` function: for this, we will need the `RecursiveDo` extension, which allows us to tie the knot in the `unloop` function even while we're inside the IO monad.

```hs
unloopPrint :: WriterT a (ReaderT a IO) b -> IO b
unloopPrint m = mdo
  (x,w) <- runReaderT (runWriterT m) w
  pure x

repminPrint :: (Ord a, Show a) => Tree a -> IO (Tree a)
repminPrint = unloopPrint . traverse (WriterT . ReaderT . f)
  where
    f x ~(Just (Min y)) = (y, Just (Min x)) <$ print x
```

Right: so at this stage, we have managed to write a version of `repminPrint` which uses any generic traversal to do the `repmin` function.
Of course, it still is in-order, rather than breadth-first:

```hs
>>> repminPrint (1 :& [2 :& [4 :& []], 3 :& [5 :& []]])
1
2
4
3
5
```

What's missing now is a traversal which walks over the tree in breadth-first, rather than depth-first, order. I'm going to use the function I wrote [here](https://doisinkidney.com/posts/2020-02-20-final-bft.html):

```hs
bft :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> Tree a -> f (Tree b)
bft f (x :& xs) = liftA2 (:&) (f x) (bftF f xs)

bftF :: Applicative f => (a -> f b) -> [Tree a] -> f [Tree b]
bftF t = fmap head . foldr (<*>) (pure []) . foldr f [pure ([]:)]
  where
    f (x :& xs) (q : qs) = liftA2 c (t x) q : foldr f (p qs) xs
    
    p []     = [pure ([]:)]
    p (x:xs) = fmap (([]:).) x : xs

    c x k (xs : ks) = ((x :& xs) : y) : ys
      where (y : ys) = k ks
```

All in all, that makes the following a single-pass, breadth-first `repminPrint` using an applicative traversal:

```hs
unloopPrint :: WriterT a (ReaderT a IO) b -> IO b
unloopPrint m = mdo
  (x,w) <- runReaderT (runWriterT m) w
  pure x

repminPrint :: (Ord a, Show a) => Tree a -> IO (Tree a)
repminPrint = unloopPrint . bft (WriterT . ReaderT . f)
  where
    f x ~(Just (Min y)) = (y, Just (Min x)) <$ print x

>>> repminPrint (1 :& [2 :& [4 :& []], 3 :& [5 :& []]])
1
2
3
4
5
```